# Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: google-chrome, sudo, apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to install VLC, then I ran sudo apt-get update command and it is showing this error message. How to solved it?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Just delete the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.1` file if you don't need it any more.

Comment: Also, in the future you may want to ask Ubuntu-related questions on http://askubuntu.com/ as you'll probably get more responses there.

Comment: @José Luis   ,I delete it ,but I have a new question.　　　　　　　　　　　E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't delete but rename (get rid of ".1") like this:
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list